# Nuget package to publish Helix config files

Tags: publishing, helix, nuget

OK, I'm probably getting my methodologies mixed up here!

We have a central library solution of code which is shared across Sitecore sites ... Inside of this, we have a Foundation project containing some Serialisation config files and binaries for Unicorn syncing.

We then have a standard Helix web site solution that will consume the central library solution as a NuGet package.

What we want is when the website solution is deployed (we are using Helix Publishing Pipeline but the approach shouldn't differ from Gulp/Cake scripting), the config files from the central library (nuget package) to also be deployed to the webroot.

Is this possible? What alternative ways of doing it are there?

Comment: Are you using your own NuGet server?

Comment: Add reference to you NuGet package. Set "Copy Local" = true on your reference. Then it should be present in website deployment.

Comment: My current understanding is that you will need to make sure that content from the nuget package are listed as contentFiles entries with copyToOutput=true. Take a look how [Sitecore.Demo.Shared](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Shared/) NuSpec files were set up and then consumed by HabitatHome.   I am working through this scenario myself now.